# Configuring Solr/Sarnia Fulltext Search in views

Tags: search

I am pulling in content from a Solr server using the Sarnia module, and displaying it using views. If no keyword is entered into the views fulltext filter all results are displayed, but for some reason (which I need help figuring out) the views fulltext search is not producing any results when a keyword is entered into the search box. I've spent days searching the issue queues and google but haven't found a solution. Any help appreciated.

Example query:

```
Index: sarnia_sarnia_solr_search
Keys: 'scientific explorer'
Parsed keys: array (
    0 => 'scientific',
    1 => 'explorer',
    '#conjunction' => 'OR',
  )
Searched fields: content, spell, tm_title
Filters:
    ss_type = 'product'
Sorting: fs_field_percent_savings DESC
Options: array (
    'parse mode' => 'terms',
    'conjunction' => 'OR',
    'filter class' => 'SearchApiQueryFilter',
    'search id' => 'search_api_views:shop:page',
  )
```

Update: I now get some results by going to Views>>Query settings and changing the parse-mode from multiple terms to single term. The problem is that while a search for the full title "scientific explorer" yields results, a search for just "scientific" or "explorer" comes up empty.

Comment: It would be helpful to state the reason for the down vote. Is it that I did not supply enough information, the question was not worded clearly, it's not considered appropriate for this site, duplicate or other reason? I am always willing to improve, but it's hard if I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After much digging around (and prayer) I was able to get the search working:

1. Make sure the content you wish to search by is indexed into Solr as type fulltext
2. Under /admin/config/search/search_api/server//sarnia/schema/fulltext, make sure the content you wish to search by is of type tm_* (text).

Additionally, under Views>>Query settings you can set the parse-mode to single term to get more targeted search (Exact matches) or multiple terms to get results for each word of the search phrase (or even word stem if so configured in Solr)